# Creating new random vs using same random

Tags: java, random, normal-distribution, random-seed

I'm trying to distribute a system and I need to use `nextGaussian()` from the `Random` Java class. The only way I found to break the data dependency a unique seed creates was using multiple seeds, thus, creating multiple randoms.

Let's forget about the context of my problem, I just want to know how well normalized is using multiple Random instances compared to using only one instance. In other words... How random is this `genNew` compared to `genSame`?

The code:

```
public double[] genNew(int lim, long seed)
{
    double[] rand = new double[lim];
    for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
    {
        //A random for each iteration.
        Random r = new Random(i*seed);
        rand[i] = r.nextGaussian();
    }
    return rand;
}

public double[] genSame(int lim, long seed)
{
    double[] rand = new double[lim];
    //A random for all iterations
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
        rand[i] = r.nextGaussian();
    return rand;
}
```

The results I get are very different when I apply both arrays to my code. I just can't explain why.

EDIT: I know this won't generate the same arrays, it is just that when using a big ammount of **normalized** randoms to calculate a number, both numbers should be close (because of the normalization), but they aren't.

Comment: RNG's shouldn't be used to generate one number, they produce better results when used many times. Have you checked the values produced by `genNew`?

Comment: Yes, the values suck. That's why I was wondering if I was doing something wrong...

Comment: Why do the values "suck"? Why do you believe they aren't random? As long as you use the method `genSame()`, they should be quite random, though computers can never really do random, but can come quite close. [Have a look here for more info on random numbers](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/cybercrime/2013/09/in-computers-are-random-numbers-really-random/)

Comment: You should give them a try yourself. I thought the same and it wasn't logical for me that they weren't "very" random. I was surprised too and I can't understand the behaviour. They "seem" random... but when you take the first value of different consecutive seeded Randoms, they aren't very random.

Comment: Also, check my answer below. That prime made them behave correctly. I tested this systematically. I know, it's crazy... I don't like it either. I hope I'm wrogn and I want someone to explain what the heck is going on and why I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to generate adecuate numbers and break the data dependency.

I don't understand why this factor works, but it does. I found it by chance and I've done almost a million millions tests on it and keeps working without failing.

If someone understands why this works, please tell:

```
Random r = new Random(seed * 43112609)
```

This number is a prime. That's the only clue I have, but still, I really can't understand why it works.